# Why am I getting a { error?

Tags: java, swing

I am getting java:105: error: illegal character: \29
}

I am writing a program where the user can click a right/left/up/down button and move a "ball" on a screen.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help me with this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab2a extends JFrame {

Lab2a(){
    setTitle("Lab 1b - Application #2");
    Lab2Panel p = new Lab2Panel();
    add(p);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
    frame.setTitle("Lab2 Application # 1");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Lab2Panel extends JPanel{
Lab2Button canvas = new Lab2Button();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

Lab2Panel () {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton leftButton = new JButton("left");
    JButton rightButton = new JButton("right");
    JButton upButton = new JButton("up");
    JButton downButton = new JButton("down");

    panel.add(leftButton);
    panel.add(rightButton);
    panel.add(upButton);
    panel.add(downButton);

    this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    leftButton.addActionListener(new LeftListener(canvas));
    rightButton.addActionListener(new RightListener(canvas));
    upButton.addActionListener(new UpListener(canvas));
    downButton.addActionListener(new DownListener(canvas));
}


}

class Lab2Button extends JPanel {
int radius = 5;
int x = -1;
int y = -1;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    if (x<0 || y<0) {
        x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
        y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
    }
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawOval(x,y, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

}

        public void moveLeft(){

            x -= 5;
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void moveRight(){

            x += 5;
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void moveUp(){
            y += 5;
            this.repaint();
        }

        public void moveDown(){
            y -= 5;
            this.repaint();
        }


}

class LeftListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    LeftListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
     this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     canvas.moveLeft();
    }
}
```

Sorry about that 105 is the line above this one.

```
class RightListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    RightListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      canvas.moveRight();
    }
}


class UpListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    UpListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        canvas.moveUp();
    }
}



class DownListener implements ActionListener{
    private Lab2Button canvas;

    DownListener(Lab2Button canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     canvas.moveDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell us which line is line 105?

Comment: Read the error message carefully, try to understand it, and indent your code meticulously.

Comment: I think it is indented properly and I counted the curly braces and I am not seeing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it appears that there are a few issues, but not exactly as you've described.

1. Line 15 `Lab2 frame = new Lab2();` presumably should be `Lab2a frame = new Lab2a();`, or you missed including your declaration of the `Lab2` object.
2. Once problem 1 has been resolved, the code compiles fine. That means that the error is in one of 2 places.

   1. The declaration of `Lab2` that you possibly excluded.
   2. The bytes of your source file, in which case the best idea would be either delete and re-paste in your code from another source (like StackOverflow), or better yet retype your code. You could improve formatting along the way :)

Comment: Thanks I had to retype the code under a different name thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried using your code and simply changing (line 20):

```
Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
```

to

```
Lab2a frame = new Lab2a();
```

Has it working without error on my machine.. Minus the fact that up and down are reversed :P

Edit: Also NetBeans automatically resolved your imports to this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

From what you had, this may have played a part in getting it working for me.

Comment: @user512915 You may have a hidden character messing up that line.. Try deleting it, the line above and below it and retyping them, because it is working perfectly for me.

Comment: Okay thanks we are not supposed to use IDE's in class only textpad

Comment: @user512915 I copied the code into a simple text editor and compiled and ran from the terminal, it is still working for me. Your file is named Lab2a.java yes?

Answer (score 1):

Without line numbers it's hard to guess, but it looks like you have two close braces here that you shouldn't:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
    frame.setTitle("Lab2 Application # 1");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }  <--- EXTRA

}
```

Update: if your intention was one class, with the rest being inner classes, then the brace marked extra above should be moved to the bottom of the file.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but that's the bracket closing the `Lab2a` class

Comment: That closes the class declaration before I do the other classes

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but it's just bad indenting. The one you pointed to closes the method the next one closes the class.

Comment: Depends on his intent.  Is this supposed to be one class with a bunch of inner classes?  Is this supposed to be a bunch of classes defined in a single file (bad)?

Answer (score 1):

can't understand where is error..

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Lab2 frame = new Lab2();
}
```

You mean Lab2a in this code?

Comment: Yes I missed that but it did not fix it

Comment: I edited the code to show where line 105 is. I counted the curly braces and I still don't see what I did wrong

Comment: try to put another global class in another file or make it inner class

Comment: @user512915 Are you sure? I fixed that line and it is running on my machine now.

Comment: also try to clean/rebuilt project.
I have no errors in this code. It works good

Comment: On my machine its still not working is there a way to reset the cache of my computer maybe to fix it?

Comment: How do I do this in textpad? we are not supposed to use IDE's in class